# Leaflet : tiles didn't load

Tags: javascript, polymer, leaflet

I try to use the leaflet-map with polymer.
I add the leaflet-map tag inside my template, but when loading (and waiting) there is only one tile which is displayed (in the top left) with the original configuration (no leaflet-tilelayer, only set the latitude, longitude and zoom)

I switch to non-polymer version of leaflet, and try invalidateSize function, and there is always the same problem? I think i've missed something, but I don't know why.

Does anyone have any idea?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the solution, the leaflet-map was inside a div with a hidden$= attributes, which seems to be a little problem